# How can I use Azure ACS in my Azure Mobile Service?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I know that Azure Mobile Services and ACS do not overlap by default, but I'd like to implement ACS access restrictions to my AMS. How can I do this?

I've tried retrieving the user's info from the Live service using the live access token, but I don't know how to pass that info to my ACS.